# Why is my element under another element while the second element doesn't have a z-index?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working with a React package name 'react-select' that allows me to create dropdown easily. Everything was fine until I create a page where there is multiple divs with several dropdown inside. Weirdly, they go under the next dropdown in the stack.

I can't really copy all my code, so I made something on netlify. Try to open the dropdown under the "Training" section, you should see what I am talking about. There are some empty options, but it's the same behavior anyway.

I tried to put a higher z-index on the "menu" parts (where there is options), but it didn't work.

Here is the link: https://nervous-franklin-89a3d8.netlify.app/#/demo-modify-profile

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the problem is the dropdown is trying to overlap the next section(files section in rour example). You need to add a Z-Index to the section containing the dropdown. However Z-index property only works on a positioned element. [See docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index)

So you want something like this.

```
<div style="position:relative;z-index:1{higher than other sections};">Container with dropdown in it</div>
<div>Next Section</div>
```